# UINavigationBar Disappear - Only on iOS7

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7, uinavigationbar

I am developing an app for iOS7 and later. I have a navigation bar which shows the `<` Back button after push segue.

When I run it on my iphone 5c(8.1) everything works fine. 
When I run it on my old iphone 4 (7.1) the UINavigationBar is not showing up causing malfunction to my app cause the back button won't appear and i have to close and reopen the app.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your viewDidLoad

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];
```

Comment: i have already tried this but it doesn;t work. It seems that the navigationbar is place on top outside the screen bounds

Comment: Have you added the navigationbar yourself or it was added by default using "embed in navigationcontroller"?

Comment: Using "embed in navigationcontroller"

Comment: This is weird. Can you post screenshot of the views in storyboard.

Comment: Size classes are backward compatible when: - The app is built using Xcode version 6 or later - The deployment target of the app is earlier than iOS 8 - Size classes are specified in a storyboard or xib - The value of the height component is not compact.

Comment: What does this actually means? Is their any way to solve this problem? Thanks